# Spark 'saveAsTextFile' to S3: Can't control number of files with 'coalesce'

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Python 3 with PySpark and Spark 1.6.0.  I've read that the number of files created by `saveAsTextFile()` is equal to the number of RDD partitions. However, I'm specifically coalescing the RDD to 16 partitions but only 1 file is getting written to S3 (`part-00000.gz`). What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel('WARN')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', AWS_SECRET_KEY)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

tbl = sqlContext.table(TABLE)
tbl.limit(1000000).toJSON().coalesce(16).saveAsTextFile(S3A_BUCKET_URL, compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
```

The original `TABLE` is Parquet stored in about 11,000 files (which I assume is equal to the Spark partitions?). When I don't use `limit()` and `coalesce()` on the whole table, it does attempt to create thousands of small files on S3, which takes a long time and just isn't necessary when I'd prefer fewer larger files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use `limit`. As for now (there is [an ongoing discussion on the developers list](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Limit-Query-Performance-Suggestion-td20570.html) so it may change in the future) `limit` repartitions all data to a single partition. Since `coalesce` can only decrease number of partitions it has no effect whatsoever.

For performance reasons it should be better to `sample` and `coalesce`. For example:

```
from operator import truediv

df.cache()
n = ... # Number of records to take
m = df.count()

df.sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=truediv(n / m))
```

but if you want to use exact `limit` you'll have to `repartition` instead of `coalesce`.

Comment: Makes sense that `limit` is the culprit, and I'd forgotten about `sample`! Thanks.